# LightGBM - Module not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lightgbm

i am using an online jupyter notebook and want to import LightGBM but i'm running into an issue i don't know how to troubleshoot.

i installed it using the pip install:

```
pip install lightgbm
```

and that appeared to work correctly:
[image: install info]

and i've checked for it in conda list:
[image: conda list]
which shows it..
(*yes i've restarted the kernel a number of times*) :D

then i imported it:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
```

no error - the cell runs fine.

but when i try to call it - i get the error "module not callable"

```
%%time
# LightGBM  data processing - categoricals and ints
cat = ['VehicleType','Gearbox','Brand','FuelType','NotRepaired']
con = ['Price','RegistrationYear','Power','Mileage','RegistrationMonth','NumberOfPictures','PostalCode','days_listed']
lgb_model = lgb(categorical_feature = cat)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

i've tried importing it a few different ways, and also changed the name to no avail:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
import lightgbm
from lightgbm import lightgbm
```

not sure what i've done wrong, or what to try next? when i search on the subject the vast majority of problems seem to be related to the successful installation - but (*and correct me if i am wrong here?*) if it is importing and saying the module is not callable as opposed to there is no module named, that would suggest that it is at least *partially* installed?

thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be some method after importing `lightgbm` like from your code i can see you are taking columns so it can be like

```
import lightgbm as lgb

cat = ['VehicleType','Gearbox','Brand','FuelType','NotRepaired']
con = ['Price','RegistrationYear','Power','Mileage','RegistrationMonth','NumberOfPictures','PostalCode','days_listed']

lgb.Dataset(data, categorical_feature=cat)
```

Comment: Ahh i see! i was kind of on auto pilot there - define the model for use later, etc. etc. :P thanks!